# refresh when connection timed out

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, three20

Is there a way to enable the pull to refresh when I got a connection timed out in a TTTableViewController? It seems that the user can't do anything at that point when it timed out. Please advice

Answer (score 1):

I do something else to solve this issue. If there's no content in the table, I display a refresh button on the UINavigationBar which manually calls the pull to refresh delegate:

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  [super viewDidAppear:animated];

  if ([Stations count]==0) {
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                                               initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh 
                                               target:self
                                               action:@selector(reload)] autorelease];
  }
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
- (void)reload {
  if ([self.tableView.delegate isKindOfClass:[TTTableViewDragRefreshDelegate class]]) {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:ttkDefaultFastTransitionDuration];
    self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, -60.0f);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
  }

  [super reload];
}
```

You can hide the rightbarbuttonitem if datasource was loaded successfully.

Comment: but the user would have to press this button right? to refresh it? issue is that I have my right bar button item already used

Comment: I also have a right button in the UINavigationBar, but I override it when there's no data